# AWS SES Mail service issue: Port ? timing out? STARTTLS?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, smtp

I am trying to send an email using amazon's ses service:

```
 String username = "&&&&&&";  // Replace with your SMTP username.
        String password = "&&&&&&&";  // Replace with your SMTP password.
        String host = "xxxxxxxx";
        int port = 25;
        String senderAddress = "xxxxxx";
        String receiverAddress = inputEmail;

        using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(host, port))
        {
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            String message = "Trucking On Demand received a request to reset the password for your account " + inputEmail + ".Your new password is: " + tempPassword;
            client.Send
            (
                       senderAddress,  // Replace with the sender address.
                       inputEmail,    // Replace with the recipient address.
                       message,
                      "This email was delivered through ****."
            );

        return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Why is my request timing out? I have tried searching internet but aws does not have a clear cut answer for this problem except asking me to enable TLS. I believe client.enablessl does that job. Do I need to dispose my client too? i.e. client.dispose();

Comment: Are you actually just timing out or are you getting a real error? In what region have you configured your SES account? The link that orhtej2 provided has a good example. I would start with that and then work backwards to your code. Note: you must use port 587. Port 25 is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-programmatically.html#send-using-smtp-net) you should connect to port `587`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, @Ackman.  But also, you need to have working Internet access from the instance where the code is running, if it's in EC2.

Comment: Actually in the documentation I found out that unless you explicitly communicate it to aws ses team you cannot send email to unregistered recipients.